# How to display List<Schema.Childrelationship> records in pageblocktable

Tags: apex, visualforce

**controller**

```
public class objectLists{
    public String SeletedObject {get; set;}
    public  String childObj {get;set;}
    List<SelectOption> options;

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectOptions() 
    {
         options = new List<SelectOption>();
         Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> AllObjmap   = New Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>();
         AllObjmap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

         System.debug('******All object Names******* :'+ AllObjmap.keyset());

         for(String ObjectName: AllObjmap.keySet())
         {
            List<string> objlist = new List<string>();
            objlist.add(ObjectName);
            options.add(new SelectOption(ObjectName,ObjectName));

        }
        return options;        
    }
    public void getrelatedchild()
    {
         Map<string,string> childMap = new Map<String, String>();
         List<Schema.Childrelationship> childList = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(SeletedObject).getdescribe().getChildRelationships();
    }
}
```

**vf page**

```
<apex:page controller="objectLists" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Select Object">

           <apex:actionFunction name="getchild" action="{!getrelatedchild}" oncomplete="alert('compeleted')" />

            <apex:outputPanel >Object:</apex:outputPanel>

              <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!SeletedObject}" onchange="callchild();">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectOptions}" />
              </apex:selectList> 

           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!childObj}" columns="2" var="item" id="a">

           </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageblock>   
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I'm creating picklist of Standard and custom objects, after selecting specific object I want to display related records to that object in pageblocktable. I'm able to add the objects in picklist but unable to disply related records in pageblocktable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can't specify a return type of `void`. Just return the `List<ChildRelationship>` and be done with the `Apex` involved. Here's a demo with just the `ChildRelationship` table:

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Demo
{
    public List<ChildRelationship> getRelationships()
    {
        return SObjectType.MyObject__c.getChildRelationships();
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="Demo">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!relationships}" var="relation">
            <apex:column value="{!relation.childSObject}" />
            <apex:column value="{!relation.field}" />
            <apex:column value="{!relation.relationshipName}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Interestingly, it seems like you ought to be able to use `{!$ObjectType.MyObject__c.childRelationships}` where I have `{!relationships}` and get rid of `Apex` altogether, but it does not seem to be supported.